# is it possible to controll browse(any) using python ,

Tags: python, selenium, build-automation, python-webbrowser

i am trying to control my browser using python, what I need is I give commands in terminal that should work on the browser like opening and searching for something(like scorling the bowser) and closing the browser

currently I am done with opening the browser and closing

Comment: Why do you want to use python, and how are you doing so? Please share your current code by pasting it into the question. It is very easy to open/close browsers and navigate to URLs, etc from the terminal with no python or scripting involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can by using python selenium driver.

This is simple code to test. Also don't forget to download selenium driver.
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
print(driver.title)
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search_bar.clear()
search_bar.send_keys("getting started with python")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print(driver.current_url)
driver.close()
```

Read [docs in link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: thank you bro, and is there any posiblities to scroll the web page

Comment: driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable (at least in POSIX systems like Linux or BSD) by using pipes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31413306)